# I want to write more than one value in "case when" in "where", but it doesn't

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I want to take only the values ​​that are 1 when @Quality is 1, and the values ​​that are both 0 and 1 when 0.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE Check = (CASE WHEN @Quality = 1 THEN 1 ELSE IN(0,1) END)
```

Comment: "it doesn't" means it returns a compilation error, does it not? So asking a good question starts by including the complete text of any error messages that your situation involves.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` must resolve to a single value. It can't contain arbitrary SQL fragments like `IN(0,1)`.

You can do this instead "to take only the values ​​that are 1 when @Quality is 1, and the values ​​that are both 0 and 1 when 0."

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Check IN (1, @Quality)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are actually after is this:

```
WHERE (Check = 1 AND @Quality = 1)
   OR (Check IN (0,1) and @Quality != 1) --Assuming @Quality cannot have a NULL value
```